# Calculate Voice usage in Blackberry application

Tags: networking, blackberry, java-me

In my application, I need to calculate voice usage for a blackberry device for a given time period.
Is there any API (starting from Blackberry 5.0) that would help me find out the total voice usage for a given time period or would provide the log details, for both incoming and outgoing calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/phonelogs/CallLog.html

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/phonelogs/PhoneLogs.html

All from 
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/overview-tree.html

Checked the api available since 4.0 
Hope this is what you need